# T-SQL, looking to extract drug dose from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of drug names with dose and I'm trying to extract the just the dose from the field. The difficulty comes in when I have combination drugs that have multiple doses. I can either extract the first numbers in the string, or all of them in one string with no way to separate them.

```
String 1: CARBIDOPA 48.75MG/LEVODOPA 195MG SA CAP
String 2: BUPRENORPHINE 8MG/NALOXONE 2MG SL TAB
String 3: HCTZ 12.5MG/LOSARTAN 100MG TAB
```

Desired output

```
String 1: 48.75MG/195MG
String 2: 8MG/2MG
String 3: 12.5MG/100MG
```

I could deal without the MG in the output, or even have the output be two different columns, but there are cases where drugs have three ingredients.

Comment: Seems like the real problem is the data. It should be in more tha. 1 column and more than 1 row. Even the result set you want isn't normalised.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. There should be a DOSE column for every drug, but that part is way out of my control.

Comment: You could do this looking at the string character by character within a WHILE loop. Basically find the position of the colon (":") and then start looking for a number. When you hit one, concatenate that number and each following character to your resulting string until you hit the forward slash ("/"). Then start looking for numbers again concatenating them to your result (as well as "M" or "G" if it follows numbers. So this is certainly possible, but very messy and fraught with possibilities for error (e.g. are the ever numeric digits in drug names).

Comment: @JohnHaxx, for what it's worth, it's not something easy. :) String parsing is always a PITA, but it's sort of a necessary evil that we all _get_ to deal with from time to time.

Comment: Do drug names have any numbers in them?

Comment: A few drug entries do have numbers in them, but they're outliers that I don't need. I can cut them out of my tables early with some simple WHERE statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine.

This is the hard cording solution. Use it wisely.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (STRING VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES 
('CARBIDOPA 48.75MG/LEVODOPA 195MG SA CAP'),
('BUPRENORPHINE 8MG/NALOXONE 2MG SL TAB'),
('HCTZ 12.5MG/LOSARTAN 100MG TAB')


SELECT SUBSTRING(STRING, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',STRING), CHARINDEX('/',STRING)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',STRING) + 1) --BEGIN WITH NUMBER & END WITH '/'
+
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING(STRING,CHARINDEX('/',STRING),LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('/',STRING) + 1), --RIGHT STRING
PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(STRING,CHARINDEX('/',STRING),LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('/',STRING) + 1)), --START POINT OF RIGHT STRING
CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(STRING,CHARINDEX('/',STRING),LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('/',STRING) + 1),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(STRING,CHARINDEX('/',STRING),LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('/',STRING) + 1)) + 1) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SUBSTRING(STRING,CHARINDEX('/',STRING),LEN(STRING) - CHARINDEX('/',STRING) + 1)) --LENGTH
)
FROM TEST
```

---

Test Result

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4cf03067467776e0caaa04ec7527e58)

Answer (score 3):

This works for your sample data:

```
select x.dosages
from (values ('CARBIDOPA 48.75MG/LEVODOPA 195MG SA CAP'),
             ('BUPRENORPHINE 8MG/NALOXONE 2MG SL TAB'),
             ('HCTZ 12.5MG/LOSARTAN 100MG TAB')
     ) v(str) cross apply
     (select string_agg(s.value, '/') within group (order by charindex(s.value, v2.str)) as dosages
      from string_split(replace(v.str, '/', ' '), ' ') s cross join
           (values (v.str)) v2(str)
      where s.value like '[0-9]%'
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04aeccfd8efa56a0d81d21fc5976dae0) is a db<>fiddle.

Notes:

- `v2` is needed because the aggregation in the subquery cannot use an outer reference.
- `string_split()` does not guarantee the ordering of return values.  The `charindex()` is used to provide the ordering.
- This works for your sample data.  It assumes that dosages start with a number and no other "words" start with a number.

Comment: why don't you use `where s.value like '[0-9]%MG'`? because of performance?

Comment: @jigga . . . No.  I simply assumed that the dosages start with a number (the OP explicitly talks about extracting numbers in the first paragraph).  I imagine that in some cases they might be measured in something other than milligrams; the OP is not clear.

Comment: This is awesome, but I'm on 2016 and can't STRING_AGG. I didn't even know that was a function. Will be bookmarking this for future use though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (STRING VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('CARBIDOPA 48.75MG/LEVODOPA 195MG SA CAP'),('BUPRENORPHINE 8MG/NALOXONE 2MG SL TAB'),('HCTZ 12.5MG/LOSARTAN 100MG TAB')

select *
,SUBSTRING(LEFT(string,charindex('/',string)),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',string),charindex('mg/',string))+''+
SUBSTRING(LEFT(RIGHT(STRING,charindex('/',string)),charindex('MG',RIGHT(STRING,charindex('/',string)))+1),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',LEFT(RIGHT(STRING,charindex('/',string)),charindex('MG',RIGHT(STRING,charindex('/',string)))+1)),5)MG

 from #TEST
```

Comment: This won't work for say 1000 mg because of your left function